# Pandas read_csv and DataFrame - How to use the data once loaded

Tags: python, pandas

In executing this...

```
 this_file = pd.read_csv(filepath, quotechar='"', error_bad_lines=False, index_col=False)
```

...I have no issues. The data is loaded fine (theoretically). However, utilizing the imported data is where I'm struggling.

In this particular case, the CSV file is full of events (races) with one event per row etc. The result is this...

```
 <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
 Int64Index: 50 entries, 0 to 49
 Data columns (total 43 columns):
 race_date               50  non-null values
 track_code              50  non-null values
 race_number             50  non-null values
 ...
 dtypes: float64(19), int64(7), object(17)
```

How do I read and use this data in the DataFrame?

I've tried...

```
 for race in this_file:
      print(race)
```

and I it returns all of the "field names."

Doing this...

```
 for race in this_file.iterrows():
      print(race)
```

...spits-out what seems to be tuples (?) of each row.

Because each race triggers a variety of separate actions with other DataFrames, I'd like to get able to utilize this in a loop (as an example)...

```
 race['race_date']
```

I'm sure this is simple, but the DataFrame read_csv produces doesn't seem to be following the examples in the book "Python for Data Analysis." Thank you!

**Edit**

I need to cycle through the races (rows) in the DataFrame, grab details from columns with the current race and use that info in other areas of the software.

So I tried this...

```
 for race in this_file.iterrows():
      print(race['race_date'])
```

and received this error...

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\RaceTest\build_models.py", line 7, in <module>
     raceanalysis.build_model(dataset='small')
   File "C:\RaceTest\raceanalysis\raceanalysis.py", line 70, in build_model
     print(race['race_date'])
 TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str
```

Comment: It's not clear what you actually want to do with this DataFrame (it looks like it is being read correctly, however it is not being displayed in full - as there are too many columns/rows)

Comment: I added more detail... hopefully it's clearer now.

Comment: an introduction to pandas from the on-line docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/10min.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
print(this_file[:10])
```

to see the first 10 rows.

`DataFrame` is column based, that is, each column is a stand-alone series:

```
race['race_date'][0] # take element 0 of race_date column
```

See http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html for more details.

Comment: or `this_file.head(10)` to stick with the Pandas syntax.

Comment: @RutgerKassies I prefer generic syntax to specific. What is the benefit of using `head()` please?

Comment: This shows me the fields just like above but sliced to the first ten. I'm just not grasping how to take the data and utilize it.

Comment: @TravisVOX it shows you column and index headings and the first ten records to be precise.

Comment: Probably won't work as there are too many columns to display.

Comment: @AndyHayden you are probably right, just noticed it has 43 columns.

Comment: Thanks. For some reason, I was thinking backwards with this whole part of the project. I appreciate your help.